# how to select from sql?

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sql, database

I have a sql statment in my app (basic4android) which is:

```
 <i>"SELECT * FROM `TempCodes` WHERE `Code` = '" & TempCode & "'"</i>
```

After running this and sending to php file I get this error:

> SELECT * FROM `TempCodes` WHERE `Code` = \'522925\'\n You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'522925\'' at line 1

And I have no idea what it means! I've tried so many things but no luck.

Comment: Are you sending the whole query to a php file?

Comment: Ah, it looks like your quotes are getting mangled (escaped when they should not be). It is generally a bad idea to allow clients to send arbitrary sql to your server/php code. This query fails, but your php file would probably have no problem handling `DROP TABLE TempCodes`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL use *prepared statements with placeholder values* and don't just [inject arbitrary content](http://bobby-tables.com) as this creates huge security risks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `code` is of integer type and you are trying to compare it with a string value by wrapping the value inside quotes. Try removing the quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM TempCodes WHERE Code = " & TempCode
```

Comment: That should not cause an error though. Incorrect results possibly; but not an error.

Comment: thank's ! that's works ! but i found another problem ! "INSERT INTO `TempCodes`(`ID`, `PhoneNumber`, `Code`, `Time`, `Date`) VALUES (null, "", "", "", "")"   even with this code and empty values i still get that error !

Comment: First if `ID` is the primary key and you are not allowed to insert `null` into a primary key. Also regarding other four columns, you can insert `empty strings` only to columns whose types are `string`. If their types are not `string` you need to replace the `empty strings` with `null` if they are `nullable`. Please if you could find your original post's answer here mark it as answer and create new posts for other questions.